# Getting AngularJS directives to update

Tags: angularjs

Trying to push my understanding directives in AngularJS to the next level. I've read the book and made a lot of progress, but this is stumping me a bit. I think there's a basic bit of key understanding I am still missing.

Let's say on a view I have two directives. The directives are side by side, not nested within each other. They do not share scope in any way (that I am aware of). Both directives inject the same service. Upon clicking an item in Directive #1 the click handler calls a function on the service that changes something within the service which Directive #2 should react to. For example, let's say I had a "Logout" directive and a "My Account" directive. Upon clicking on "Logout", I want the "My Account" directive to dim out, or perhaps have the text change to "Please log in". The "Logout" directive is calling  myService.logout(), and the "My Account" directive scope is perhaps bound to myservice.someObj.isLoggedIn(). The isLoggedIn() function starts returning false when the click happens.

How can I get the second directive to know that something happened? Can I trigger a function call within the directive upon an important change happening? How do I set up the scope of the directive to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want help writing, changing, fixing, debugging, or doing anything else with code, please post the actual code you are working with, but please, no untested "examples" or pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Logout` directive, you can use `$scope.$emit` to pass the message `LOGOUT_TRIGGERED` to a parent scope.

In the parent scope, use `$scope.$on` to listen to that message. On receiving that message, just dispatch the message `HANDLE_LOGOUT` to the `Account` directive via `$scope.$broadcast`.

In the `Account` directive, using `$scope.$on` again to listen to that `HANDLE_LOGOUT` message.

- `$scope.$emit` sends message to all parent scopes
- `$scope.$broadcast` sends message to all child scopes

Or you can check this `EventDispatcher` service:
https://github.com/trochette/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices/blob/master/js/base/EventDispatcher.js

Answer (score 2):

In your directive you can have the "My Account" button watch the service for a change. You just need to do a

```
$scope.$watch(mysevice.someObj.isLoggedIn, function() {

   //do something

})
```

Alternatively you could also have the first button `$scope.$broadcast` once its logged out and have the second service watch for that broadcast using `$scope.$on`.

**UPDATE**

```
 app.directive('directiveName', function () {
     restrict: 'AE',
     link: function ($scope, element, attrs){
         $scope.$watch(myservice.someObj.isLoggedIn, function () {
             // do stuff
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Can you tell me how scope should be set up in the directive?

I am trying it with scope: true, and so far that does not seem to work. I tried logging to the console in the $watch function and I only see it being called upon the directive first being loaded even though I am definitely changing what is being watched.

Comment: You can also use `$scope.$broadcast` or `$scope.$on` the same way. Make sure you're also injecting the service into the directive.

Comment: $rootScope.$broadcast() and $rootScope.$on worked perfectly and seem the most straightforward, however perhaps there is badness to using $rootScope I am not aware of. These all seem like different methods of achieving the same goal: to update scope in a timely manner. I would love to find an overview of the design tradeoffs of one technique versus another.